# Error when running 'hdparm --dco-identify' in Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hdparm

DCO: Device Configuration Overlay

HPA: Host Protected Area

Both are 'hidden' areas on a HDD.

I am trying to detect if my HDD has a DCO and remove it/ restore to factory settings. This is so that I can then securely erase all data on the HDD properly. I do not want hidden data in the HPA and DCO to get left behind. HPA is disabled so I am checking for a DCO.

I entered "**sudo hdparm --dco-identify /dev/sda**"

Terminal returned "**HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(dco_identify) failed: Input/output error**"

Does this mean I don't have a DCO or have I made an error in entering the command?

---

When I run "**sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda**"
Security says:

> Security:
>
> Master password revision code = [redacted just in case it's sensitive
>   data]
>
> supported
>
> not   enabled
>
> not   locked
>
> frozen
>
> not   expired: security count
>
> supported: enhanced erase

Could this have something to do with the error? My drive is "frozen". Both my laptop and desktop drives say this.

Related post: [How to un freeze drive in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1161531/how-to-un-freeze-drive-in-linux)

Comment: What version of hdparm do you use?  Try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade  -->>This was fixed in hdparm-9.37!

Comment: I am running the Linux Mint 18.1 Serena Cinnamon Live CD. I tried

Comment: I mean what hdparm version do you use ?

Comment: I accidentally submitted the previous comment and then tried to edit it. It's not letting me edit.

my post: 
I am running the Linux Mint 18.1 Serena Cinnamon Live CD. I tried "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade". It returned an error suggesting it is not happy with me running that command on a live cd. I will update my original post with the output/ result from the terminal.

Comment: I have deleted my previous comments and deleted the edit I previously made due to them now being irrelevant. Instead of running a Live CD, I have installed Linux on a 16GB USB and have updated all software successfully. I have also confirmed that I have updated to the latest version of hdparm which is 9.48. It is still giving me the same error!!

Comment: Worth pointing out this is still happening. I get the same error on my laptop as well. I have been unable to find a single person online who has experienced or resolved this.

Comment: https://tinyapps.org/docs/wipe_drives_hdparm.html shows the author successfully executing --dco-identify but their drive is not listed as frozen. How do I unfreeze my drive?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

Refer to [How to un freeze drive in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/1161531/how-to-un-freeze-drive-in-linux/1161568#1161568) for answer.

> Success!! I managed to unfreeze my drive by making the SATA port it is
>   connected to hot-swappable. This involved me going into my BIOS. How
>   you can achieve this will vary depending on your BIOS manufacturer.
>
> Once the SATA port was hot-swappable, I did the following: 1) turned
>   pc off 2) disconnected the SATA data cable from my motherboard. Left
>   power cable connected. 3) turned PC on and booted into Linux 4)
>   Connected HDD and Viola! It was unfrozen and "sudo hdparm
>   --dco-identify /dev/sdb" was working! 5) I checked to confirm it was unfrozen by running "sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb"
>
> Note: device is at sdb now and not sda (as you will find in my other
>   thread - linked above) because the HDD was connected after Linux was
>   booted into!
>
> Credit:
>   https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/714345-connecting-hdd-after-computer-has-been-turned-on/#comment-9107915
>
> If you cannot make your drive hot-swappable, you will have to buy a
>   SATA-USB cable and connect your drive via USB.